# Hotel Management

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

Hi all I got stuck with one problem i.e in booking section if the room is already booked it should create an exception displaying the room is already booked and also the same room could be booked in advanced after the check out date here is the code which I used:

```
@api.one  
@api.onchange('time_date')  
def onchange_same(self):
    x=self.env['hotel.management'].search([('room','=','self.room.room')])
# check_out = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.env['hotel.management'].search([('room','=','self.room.room')]).check_out, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    time_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.time_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    check_out = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.check_out, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    if x:
        if time_date>=x.check_out:
            pass
        else:
            print 'working till now--------'
            raise except_orm('Payment Error!',"This room is booked please select another one")
```

However it's displaying:

> Type Error: must be string, not bool

Comment: don't use api.one api.onchange is enough.          what are u doing here ([('room','=','self.room.room')])
use like :   ([('room' ,'=', self.room.room)])

Comment: By mistake I added quotes thanks for pointing it out however it wont help me out with this thanks

Answer (score 1):

When ever we are fetching any value from the database, first we need to check this condition => weather field has store value or not.

Second thing (in your case) have problem with *search()* method.

General syntax for search() method:

```
self.env['model.name'].search(['field_name', 'operator', 'value'])
```

Try with this code:

```
@api.one  
@api.onchange('time_date')  
def onchange_same(self):

    x=self.env['hotel.management'].search([('room','=',self.room.room)])
    if self.time_date or self.check_out:
        time_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.time_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        check_out = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.check_out, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        if x and x.check_out:
            if time_date>=x.check_out:
                pass
            else:
                print 'working till now--------'
                raise except_orm('Payment Error!',"This room is booked please select another one")
    else:
        print "\n=====date not define"
```

For more about [Odoo Search method](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.search)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Odedra for guiding me but I resolved with following code.

```
@api.onchange('time_date')  
def onchange_same(self):
    x=self.env['hotel.management'].search([('room','=',self.room.room)])   
    if x:
        if self.time_date>=x.check_out:
            pass
        else:
            print 'working till now--------'
            raise except_orm('Payment Error!',"This room is booked please select another one")
```